# select option clears when page loads in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, select

the scenario is this: see select below

```
<form name="limit">
    <select name="limiter" onChange="limit(this.value)">
        <option selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want whenever any option is selected for 3 things to happen:

1.) js limit() function is called which all it does its takes current url, adds new query parameter 'limit' with the user selected value eg:

http://localhost/blahblah/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021&**limit=5**

(this will cause the category.php page to be hit and # of product displayed limited to the value selected by user)

2.)Once the url is hit, it reloads but i **DONT** want the value selected to reset back to the default (which it currently does). I want it to reflect the users selection after page reload.

3.) Also, when i move to the next page (pagination), i would like the state to be carried ova to the next page (ie. remembering the user selection).

Comment: Hi! As you put a bounty on this question, I suppose that the already provided answers have not helped you solve your problem. Could you edit your question to add a few informations about what is not OK with the existing answers ? *(It might help one give you a better one, by better understanding your problem :-) )*

Answer (score 8):

Just assign the selected value using PHP:

```
<form name="limit">
    <select name="limiter" onChange="limit()">
        <option <?php if(!isset($_POST['limiter'])) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>&nbsp;</option>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['limiter']) && $_POST['limiter'] == 5) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="5">5</option>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['limiter']) && $_POST['limiter'] == 10) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="10">10</option>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['limiter']) && $_POST['limiter'] == 15) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="15">15</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

As the code gets hard to read, you could do a loop instead with PHP:

```
<form name="limit">
    <select name="limiter" onChange="limit()">
        <option <?php if(!isset($_POST['limiter'])) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>&nbsp;</option>
        <?php foreach(array(5, 10, 15) as $p): ?>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['limiter']) && $_POST['limiter'] == $p) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $p; ?>">
            <?php echo $p; ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limit(value)
    {
        url = "localhost/yourapp?limiter="+value;
    }
</script>

<form name="limit">
    <select name="limiter" onChange="limit(this.value)">
        <option>&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($_REQUEST['limiter'] == 5) {echo "selected";}?>>5</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if($_REQUEST['limiter'] == 10) {echo "selected";}?>>10</option>
        <option value="15" <?php if($_REQUEST['limiter'] == 15) {echo "selected";}?>>15</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I am using `$_REQUEST` here because I don't know your form's method. Use accordingly.

Comment: hello gaurav, though the select element is wrapped in a form, it doesnt actually have a submit button. onchange it calls a javascript which then builds the url pointing to a php file which then passes the parameters set on the url and acts accordingly...so when I say $_REQUEST['limiter'] it complains of undefined index 'limiter'

Comment: this error is happening because your there is no method attribute in your form tag.
If you don't want to use submit method then you will have to pass the value that is being selected in the select box and then check it accordingly.

I have edited my answer to explain, (may have minor errors that you can correct quite easily)

Answer (score 0):

Tatu Ulmanen's answer handles the part of displaying select.  To do the pagination part, simply pass the limit as a parameter in the query string.

For example, if you're currently using page links that look like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/blahblah/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021">1</a>
```

Change them to include your limit parameter so it gets passed over:

```
<a href="http://localhost/blahblah/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId-3021&limit=5">1</a>
```

Just make sure to change your pagination code to account for the fact that each page is only "limit" items long.  To help you do that, I need to know how you were doing your pagination.

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether it works?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function limit(myvalue)
{
location.href="http://yoursite?limit="+myvalue;
}

function querySt() {
hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
gy = hu.split("&");
for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
ft = gy[i].split("=");
if (ft[0] == 'limit') {
for (var idx=0;idx<document.getElementById('limiter').options.length;idx++) {
            if (document.getElementById('limiter').value==ft[1]) {
                  document.getElementById('limiter').selectedIndex=idx;


                  }

                  }
}
}

}

   </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="querySt()">
 <form name="limits"> 
    <select onchange="limit(this.value)" id="limiter"> 
        <option selected="selected">&nbsp;</option> 
        <option value="5">5</option> 
        <option value="10">10</option> 
        <option value="15">15</option> 
    </select> 
</form> 

 </body>
```